# Using multiple tables to find cost by transactiondate and location

Tags: sql

I am trying to create a query that joins 3 tables with multiple prices and locations. Ex of the data I'm pulling.

**Table A** - product, product name

**Table B** - transactionid, date, product, returnreason, quantity, costprice, costamount,
          location, journalid

**Table C** - price1, price2, price3, price4, price5, price6, product, activedate

**Table C** is updating prices for our products and can be the same from one date to another, or completely change depending on the market. Location in Table B can be up to four different locations.

Ex. Table C (each product is setup basically the same in the tables.)

```
product   price1    price2    price3    price4    price 5    price6    activedate 
A         0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00       0.00      1/1/11 
A         0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00       0.00      2/1/11 
A         1.00      0.00      0.63      0.00      1.20       0.20      1/1/12 
A         1.20      0.53      0.01      1.00      0.42       0.00      4/1/13
```

Table B

```
product  transactionid  tdate  returnreason  quantity costprice  costamount location journalid
A        00001         5/1/11   def          100        2.00        2.50      100     000010
B        00205         6/13/11  col          250       10.00       15.00      300     000320
A        00207         4/11/13  col          50         5.00        1.50      100     000720
```

I need to get the information out by the most current price for the item by date. So if I need a yearly report, I can see that for product A - price1 for 1/1/13-4/30/13 was 1.00 and for 5/1/13-present the price is now 1.20.

I have tried many things including sub queries and the latest (which is closest) to limit it by creating a where statement to be activedate<=tdate which will bring me every active date below and equal to the tdate. For this please assume product A is at location 100. How can I limit to the product active during the time frame it would be active?

Most recent...
I added line number in to make sure I got each line of the journal in...just visual.

select distinct(b.transactionid), b.tdate, b.linenum b.product, b.location,
       b.journalid, c.price1, c.price2, c.price3, c.price4, c.price5, c.activedate
      from Table b inner join
           Table c on c.product=b.product
      where c.activedate <= b.tdate

When I run this I get all dates that were less than the transaction date, but I need specific. For example the first transaction in my example, it happened on 5/1/11, when I run the query it will give me the results from table c for 1/1/11 and 2/1/11. I just need the date of the price for when the transaction took place.

Comment: It's usually a good idea to post your attempts to solve the problem yourself even if they were unsuccessful.

Comment: SQL Server 2008 R2...I have had so many that were unsuccessful. I tried using a max date in a sub query, but it's not really the top date that I need. It's the date of the transaction that I need.